# Passing parameter to request via ajax and printing it with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parameters, request

I have in my index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var chosenCity = 'London';

    (function($) {

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("city", chosenCity);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "index.php");
        xhr.send(formData);     

    })(jQuery);


</script>
```

I want to print in my page the value of chosenCity, so I do:

```
<?php 
    $var = $_REQUEST['city'];
    echo $var;
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

But nothing is printed.

Using a php debugger I can see that $var contains null at first load, in a fisrt debug session.

And in a second debug session `$var` contains `'London'`... nevertheless nothing is printed even after this second session.

The same happens trying to print `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`

I've tried different environments and browsers

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: any errors in console??

Comment: no errors, totally clean

Comment: In Network tab of your developer tools, make sure that `Request Method` is `POST`, if not probably you're send `GET` request to server...

Comment: Can you provide us with some more information please.

Comment: What the index.php suppose to do?

Comment: Please post the code of index.php

Comment: the only code index.php has is the one I already posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the jQuery for a moment the following works fine which suggests that your javascript code for sending the XHR request itself is fine.

```
    <?php
        /* 

            "/test/target.php" ~ equivilent of index.php

        */
        ob_clean();
        print_r($_POST);
        exit();
    ?>


    function _ajax( chosenCity ){
        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('city', chosenCity);
        fd.append('section','baselevel');

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ) console.info( 'Response: %s',xhr.response );
        };
        xhr.open( 'POST', '/test/target.php' );
        xhr.send( fd );     
    }

    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){ _ajax.call(this,'london') }, false );
```